# How to place partially initialized struct object into a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11

I currently have struct where I initialize only two of three member. I purposefully do this since during the time of creation I am not sure what the value will be  ( I actually am fine with it being just zero).

```
struct my_data {
    my_data(int x_, int y_) {
       x = x_;
       y = y_;
    }


    int x;
    int y;
    double z = 0;
};

int main() {
   std::vector<my_data> my_vec;
   my_vec.resize(10);

   my_vec[0] = {3,4};
}
```

When I do this I get `error: no matching function for call .... _T1(std::forward<Args ..`

Is there any way to avoid this error or should I have to include `z` also in as parameter in constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a default constructor:

```
my_data() = default;
```

Comment: is that for vector.resize()'s call for default constructor?

Comment: @solti, yes - vector.resize() expects it. Whats wrong with `my_vec[0] = {3,4};` ?

Comment: oh ok! thank you.  Sorry abt `my_vec[0] = {3,4};` that was my bad .. you can ignore it

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, you can make `my_data` easier to use by removing the constructor and the default value of `z`.

```
struct my_data {
    int x;
    int y;
    double z;
};

int main() {
   std::vector<my_data> my_vec;
   my_vec.resize(10);

   my_vec[0] = {};           // Same as = {0, 0, 0};
   my_vec[1] = {3};          // Same as = {3, 0, 0};
   my_vec[2] = {3, 4};       // Same as = {3, 4, 0};
   my_vec[3] = {3, 4, 2.0};
}
```